# Remove indexed data from solr index

Tags: solr, indexing

How to remove particular data from solr indexed fileds.
e.g. 
Indexed

No | Rank | Field    | Text
1  | 95   | content  | data
2  | 80   | content  | hrkg

(seen thr' luke jar file)

So I have to remove only the 'hrkg' entry from indexed 'content' field, not all documents.

Comment: Is the 'hrkg' a filed or some data from 'hrkg' entry in DIH that will get into the 'content' field?

Comment: 'hrkg' is text(data) in content field which is indexed by solr.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to understand you, but:

1. If u want to remove ONE field value, simply insert again into SOLR with the same document id, but leave the field value this time empty (or put the new value you want).
2. Delete this document by id `<delete><query>id:[DOCUMENT ID TO DELETE]</query></delete>`

Comment: Thanx.....

Actually I want to remove some content from indexed field, not document.

i.e. suppose indexed field is Person and it contains 'Zokgh' value, I want to remove 'Zokgh' value from that indexed Person field.

See the below table.


2 | 80 | Person| Zokgh , where Person is field and Zokgh is indexed text.

Answer (score 1):

well... i can comment as my points are not enough... but if you are using solr 4.0 (alpha or beta) you can simply run an update query on the specific field for the document.. `curl 'localhost:8983/solr/<yourcore>/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"blabla","<fieldtochange>":{"set":"new value"}}]'`

Answer (score 0):

Once you indexed some data and put it into the field that contains also data you do not want to remove, there is not much options left.

Actually I can't see another way but remove 'hrkg' from you configs and **reindex affected documents**.

To remove (hide) whole filed for all docs is much easier.